# Regular Expression to match `#import`

Tags: regex

Things I want to match:

```
#import
 #import
```

Things I don't want to match:

```
#important
import
_#import
a#import
```

I've tried using `\b#import\b` and `\b\#import\b` but they won't match `#import` (they do match `_#import` and `a#import` tho)

So what regex pattern should I use for this? Any help would be appreciated.

---

#### Edit

To make it clearer what I want to achieve, I tried `\bvoid\b` with some strings and the results are shown below:

```
void //match
 void //match
(void) //match
void_ //didn't match
```

And I expected that I can get similar result when replacing `void` with `#import`. However, using `\b#import\b` won't match any of the following:

```
#import
 #import
(#import)
#import_
```

So what's the problem here?

Comment: with regards to your edit - perhaps you should capitalize the first \b like the answer did? \B#import\b matches all but #import_ for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```regex
\B#import\b
```

Since `#` is not a word character, `\B` is needed in order to make sure it isn't beside another word character.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zX9zO9/2)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.